# Regression with Categorical Covariates matlab error

Tags: matlab, regression

I am trying to run the example at:
http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/group-comparisons-using-categorical-arrays.html

using Matlab R2013b.

```
clear
load('carsmall')
cars = table(MPG,Weight,Model_Year);
cars.Model_Year = nominal(cars.Model_Year);
fit = fitlm(cars,'MPG~Weight*Model_Year')
```

Unfortunatelly I get the error:

```
Error using classreg.regr.FitObject/assignData (line 257)
Predictor and response variables must have the same length.

Error in classreg.regr.TermsRegression/assignData (line 349)
            model = assignData@classreg.regr.ParametricRegression(model,X,y,w,asCat,varNames,excl);

Error in LinearModel.fit (line 852)
            model = assignData(model,X,y,weights,asCatVar,dummyCoding,model.Formula.VariableNames,exclude);

Error in fitlm (line 111)
model = LinearModel.fit(X,varargin{:});
```

Any clue why?

Comment: "Predictor and response variables must have the same length" - it is telling you that your output variable has a different number of observations from your input variables. It's a dimension mismatch error. You must debug to find out what the dimensions are and why they differ

Comment: Hi Dan, does it run properly for you? This is the code example taken from the help